# How to Include Testing tools in Visual Studio 2013 Community

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, configuration, coded-ui-tests

I have installed Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition in my PC and i created a new project using Visual C# ---> Test ----> Unit Test Project as show bellow.

[image]

But My problem is I want to add Codded UI testing instead of Unit Test Project. Can any one help me how to install testing tools for Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition.

Comment: Have you added the Coded UI Extension via Tools -> Extensions & Updates?

Comment: No where i can i check this. @RagtimeWilly

Comment: In Visual Studio go select Extensions and Updates from the Tools menu. Then select Online from left hand nav and search for Coded UI.

Comment: From looking at this link: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/51b4a94a-1878-4dcc-81e0-7dc92131d2da it appears it may only be available for Premium or Ultimate editions of Visual Studio.

Comment: ok Thank you. It suggested me Ranorex- Automated Testing....., Axe - Test Automation Platform, M - eux test. Which one will be best. @RagtimeWilly

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have experience with those frameworks so I can't make a recommendation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Coded UI Plugin](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/51b4a94a-1878-4dcc-81e0-7dc92131d2da) is only available for Premium or Ultimate editions of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at TestStack White (http://docs.teststack.net/White/GettingStarted.html) as an alternative for Coded UI. Since Coded UI is only available in Premium+ versions of Visual Studio.

Example code for White:

```
    public void Notepad() {
        Application app = Application.Launch("notepad.exe");
        Window window = app.GetWindow("Untitled - Notepad");

        // Change text
        var box = window.Get(SearchCriteria.ByClassName("Edit"));
        Keyboard.Instance.Send("test", box);

        // Save
        window.MenuBar.MenuItem("File", "Save As...").Click();
        var filename = window.Get(SearchCriteria.ByClassName("Edit"));
        Keyboard.Instance.Send(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssffff") + "test.txt", filename);
        window.Get(SearchCriteria.ByText("Save")).Click();

        app.Kill();
    }
```